# Как ввести ограничение на загрузку изображений при массовой загрузке?

Tags: php, html, javascript

Есть у меня такая форма мульти загрузки изображений

```
<form action='../upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input name='file[]' type='file' multiple='true' />
<input type='submit' value='Загрузить' />
</form>
```

Я хочу чтобы пользователь мог загрузить только 5 изображений за раз! Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html — никак, такое ограничение нужно сделать на сервере, либо отрезайте на клиенте и загружайте через ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name='file[]' type='file' min="1" max="5" multiple='true' />
```

Comment: Это поддерживает только Opera и то до 15 версии.